# Adding audio button to image target?

Tags: button, audio, augmented-reality, vuforia

I’m a complete newbie to Unity and Vuforia and am struggling to create a button that plays an audio file when pressed. I’ve tried all the YouTube videos but their code never seems to work for me, no matter how much I check.

I’m working on a AR app that will show a character when an image target is scanned, and want the viewer to hear the character speak when they press a button essentially.

Does anyone have a step-by-step guide or up to date code that might work?

Would be eternally grateful!

I’ve exhausted the YouTube resources out there I think.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, just edit your question, and put what have you tried. Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you want to make a button that plays audio. Here's how you could make it:

1. Right-click on the inspector. Find "UI" > "Canvas"
2. Right-click on the canvas. Find "UI" > "Button" or "Button Text-Mesh-Pro" and Customize the button however you like
3. Create a script called "PlayAudio" (you can name it whatever you want) attach it to the canvas, and double-click the script
4. In the script, delete both start() and update() functions and make a new AudioSource before the start function. In the inspector, attach your .mp3 to the field. After you've done this, make a new **PUBLIC** function called "playAudioButton" so in the end, it should look like this:

```
public AudioSource audio;
 
public void playAudioButton ()
{   
    audio.Play();
}
```

5. Now, go back to your button, scroll to the very bottom and you'll see the "OnClick" function. Click the plus icon. Drag the canvas to the gameobject field, select the name of the script, and select "playAudioButton()"

Now it should work. If it doesn't work, then you may be missing an event system.